# North-facing rocks that soak up polar sunlight

Tags: knowledge, science

Chapter 155 in the book *'365 Surprising Scientific Facts, Breakthroughs, and Discoveries'* of Sharon Bertsch McGrayne (Wiley, 1994) states that:

> North-facing rocks that soak up polar sunlight can be 15°C
>   (60°F) warmer than the surrounding air.

What's really strange about this statement?

Comment: Simply that polar sunlight is not really a thing? Or is it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is strange because

> The formula to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit is: $ºC = \frac{ºF - 32}{ 1.8}$ so a difference a difference of $1°C$ corresponds to a difference of $1.8 °F$ so a difference of $15°C$ is a difference of $27°F$
>
>  This book is confusing the conversion $15°C$ = $60°F$ with the conversion of $\Delta ºC$ to $\Delta ºF$.

Comment: I always tried to distinguish in my teaching between 5 *Celsius degrees*, and 5 *degrees Celsius*.  Similar to *5 miles* on Interstate 94, and *Mile 5* on Interstate 94

Answer (score 8):

Celsius and Fahrenheit have different starting points, so converting between absolute temperatures is not the same as converting between relative temperatures (i.e. differences). This book converted an absolute temperature of 15 degrees Celsius rather than a relative temperature difference: the correct value would be only about 27 degrees.

Answer (score 5):

Hmmm...where should I start?

> "north facing rocks". how can rocks have a face?

But let's say they do.
It is kind of strange to ...

> receive sunlight when you are facing north. But this can still happen if you are at the south poll. Then it's north in every direction

Comment: But the question does not ask whether it could be true. It simply asks what is strange. Which is strange btw

Comment: @fffred. I explained what I think is strange. I also added my personal thoughts that this can still happen. Is it strange that I did that?

Comment: Your answer is fine. But your reason why it could be true sounds like a puzzle solution, not real science, and the question cites something real it seems. Well, I guess this could still be the right answer

Comment: Rocks that are close enough to the north-pole **can** receive sunlight on the north-facing side, since earths axial tilt is currently ~23.4°. Inside the arctic circle there's a season, when the sun doesn't set for a few days to month, depending on  how far north the position is and thus as well shines, when it's north from the viewer. And we can define "north facing" as "the largest side of the rock is on the north-side of the rock"

Answer (score 2):

If we take the direction absolute:

> The sun is never in the North. It comes up in the East, travels over South to the West. North-facing rocks will not soak up any (direct) light because the sun is never there.

Comment: @Lordofdark is probably right though, that's the biggest flaw.

Comment: The north pole is ice, and under the ice is sea. there are no rocks at the north pole. so clearly the rocks are at the south pole.

Comment: @Jasen Is polar light something only happening at the exact poles? I'd assume Greenland and Svalbard would be possible locations as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is strange because

> rocks that are 15 degrees Celsius warmer will be above freezing, thereby eliminating permafrost and melting ice multiple months out of the year.